# PayPal personal account: does it accept credit cards or not?

Tags: canada, credit, paypal, chargeback

On this website it says it does not:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pop/choosing_account_type_signup-outside

On this site it says it does:

https://www.paypal.com/re/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/general/PayPalAccountTypes-outside

So which is it? The reason I am asking is because if a personal account does not allow credit cards then a donator cannot file chargeback. If they do file chargeback then I don't want this to happen

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support/server-administration/1936535-paypal-chargebacks-on-server-donation

The logic here is that since a personal account does not accept credit or debit the customer cannot file chargeback through their bank and instead has to use PayPal's dispute system which is much safer.

Bottom line is:
Does a PayPal personal account accept credit or debit payment? And if not does that mean I cannot get a chargeback? Only a PayPal dispute?

Comment: Sanity check: Have you tried sending mail to PayPal support asking this?

Comment: Sorry I have not because I need a paypal account to do that. And I need to know what account to make so I asked here. It's a Catch 22. EDIT: nevermind, found it, https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_contact-general I just had to look to the right a bit.

Comment: Personal accounts have sending & receiving limits. Their reasoning is that a personal account is not being used for business (e.g. accepting credit card). They do not charge fees for sending and receiving with a personal account, so they do not want business users to abuse personal account features. Paypal frowns on buyers initiating chargebacks wants customers use their dispute system. You are not the only one who dislikes chargebacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [PayPal's external help page on account types](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?articleID=FAQ2347&m=SRE&url=https%253A%252F%252Fokminternal.paypal.com%252Finfocenter%252Findex%253Fpage%253Dcontent%2526id%253DFAQ2347%2526actp%253Dsearch%2526viewlocale%253Den_US&answerId=16777217&searchId=1410128396500&rankId=2), basic accounts can not accept credit cards; you need to upgrade at least to a Premier account to do so.

Their [help center](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/home/) gives both phone and e-mail contacts if you want to discuss this with someone who actually knows what they're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using PayPal personnel account .I can use credit card on my account. Sometime it may not possible in your country.

Comment: Personal accounts can pay with credit cards. Supposedly, they can't accept payment from credit cards. If that's working for you, great, but...